# OpenMp and opencv crash on big arrays

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize function using openMp, and I'm getting random crashes when increasing size of matrix. On single thread everything works fine even on single Mat size up to 6000x4000, but crashes on openMp. Interestingly when size of Mat's is reduced to 3000x2000 it's working fine.

```
        std::vector<std::string> Image_path;
        for (int iI = 0; iI < 10; ++iI) {
            Image_path.emplace_back("test" + std::to_string(iI) + ".bmp");
        }
        std::vector<cv::Mat> Images(Image_path.size());
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int iI = 0; iI < Image_path.size(); ++iI) {
            Images[iI] = cv::imread(Image_path[iI], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        }
```

Edit: Crashes occurs at cv::imread, but only when #pragma is uncommented.
When inscrising stack size crash still happends.
When putting cv::imread in crittical section crash do not occur.
I port the code to openCv source code to trace exact line with couse problem, and it did not happend. When I incrise size of images to 12000x8000 all works fine.

OpenCv 3.0, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013 120mvc 64 bit.
Crash - Acces violation at reading location

Comment: Where does it crash ?

Comment: The question is whether `cv::imread` function is _thread-safe_. I couldn't find anything about it in OpenCV documentation. However, I don't think you will get any speedup by reading files in parallel. I/O will be likely the bottleneck here and it will not benefit from concurrency, if you, e.g., do not have a parallel file system.

Comment: I'm using standard PC, and for sizes small as 3000x2000 (with do not couse crashes), speed up is significant (4 cores, 8 threads like 4-5 time faster), imread must be doing more then just I/O. All data are readed correctly.

Comment: @CzakCzan All right. Try to increase the stack size for threads. Maybe, the `cv::imread` uses the stack intensively somehow. `export OMP_STACKSIZE=32M`. Does it help?

Comment: @CzakCzan Not also, that the observed behavior dosn't imply, that the function is _thread-safe_.

Comment: @CzakCzan By the way, what happens if you wrap function the call inside the loop with `#pragma omp critical`?

Comment: @CzakCzan Thanks for clarification. It seems that `cv::imread` is not thread-safe. If it's not, then it makes no sense to try to find out when it works and when it doesn't; it should not be used by multiple threads concurrently.

Comment: [mcve], please. | OpenCV version? Platform? Compiler? 32bit or 64bit? | "It crashes" is a pretty useless description of the problem, elaborate. Uncaught exception? Segfault? Something else?

Comment: Try limiting the number of threads. I've had this problem in the past, caused by OpenMP dispatching too many threads.

Comment: I tryed to limit number of processes to one less then hardvare concurency but it did not solve problem. Is there any way to check what amount of thread can safely be dispatched,to achieve at least some multithreading?